# CSS won't connect to my WordPress site when using wampserver, I can't seem to find an answer anywhere

Tags: css, wordpress

I am learning wordpress through a learning website and I've got everything written exactly as they do, yet I just can't seem to get my stylesheet to connect. I'm currently using wampserver and my editor is visual studio code. I've looked through the codex, stackoverflow, and whatever else I can find out there to help me but nothing seems to be working.

Functions.php:

```
<?php

function learningwordpress_styles() {

    //add the stylesheets
    wp_register_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('normalize'), '1.0.0');
    wp_register_style('normalize', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/normalize.css', array(), '8.0.1');

    //enqueue the style
    wp_enqueue_style('style');
    wp_enqueue_style('normalize');

};
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'learningwordpress_styles');
```

Comment: What are all the back ticks in your code before `array`?

Comment: Those backticks were suggested by the stackoverflow to align it better. I could have been wrong about that... but if you ignore the back ticks then that is the original text. ill change it back to avoid confusion if possible.

Comment: No more back ticks

Comment: A few things, this question really belongs in the Wordpress Stackexchange. In your theme do you have a `wp_head()` function in the header and `wp_footer()` function in the footer? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer

Comment: To elaborate: the enqueues you have tell WordPress, "When the time comes, emit tags to reference these scripts and styles". But you never tell it "Now's the time". That's part of the function of `wp_head()` and `wp_footer`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I apologize for placing this question in the wrong place. As you can see, I'm still very new to this. It does work now and I am very grateful for your help. I hope you all have a wonderful day.